# Automatize using bash downloading deb files and dependencies and later extracting them to a unique folder and compress it to use in a live filesystem

Tags: apt, bash, dpkg

I am developing a live filesystem and need to be able to download deb files with their dependencies which I manually do using this command:

```
apt download $(apt-cache depends --recurse --no-recommends --no-suggests
--no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances
--no-pre-depends ${PACKAGES} | grep "^\w")
```

After that, I need to extract all `data.tar.gz` files from the required deb packages, combine them into one unique folder (the `mv` command is not very useful in merging folders) which I manually do using both `/usr/bin/ar x` or `dpkg-deb` later combined with `tar` to extract all files from `data.tar.gz` from $DEB.

Is there a bash way to automatize the whole process disregarding the number of downloaded $DEB files?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add: i) some example package names we can use to test our approaches, ii) show us the scripts you have so far and iii) tell us what your expected output would be. Alternatively, show us the directory structure and output of `ls` after downloading so we can understand what files you are working with. You will probably want something like `for deb in *deb; do ... dpkg-deb "$dev" ...; done` but the details will depend on exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Finally ended like this

```
#!/bin/bash
# Developed by Roberto Gonzalez for Slide Linux
# Root only
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 
   exit 1
fi
FILE="`echo $1 | rev | cut -d. -f2- | rev`.fs"
archiveDir=/var/cache/apt/archives
destinationDir=/run/initramfs/memory/data/modules
apt update
apt install -d "$1" -y  || { echo 'apt2fs failed' ; exit 1; }
mkdir $archiveDir 2>/dev/null
mkdir $archiveDir/deb
mkdir $archiveDir/deb/WE
mv $archiveDir/*.deb $archiveDir/deb/  || { echo 'apt2fs failed' ; exit 1; }
cd $archiveDir/deb
for z in *.deb; do ar x $z data.tar.gz | tar xfv data.tar.gz -C WE/; done 2>/dev/null
for z in *.deb; do ar x $z data.tar.xz | tar xfv data.tar.xz -C WE/; done 2>/dev/null
for z in *.deb; do ar x $z data.tar.zst | tar xfv data.tar.zst -C WE/; done 2>/dev/null
# Some cleanup
    rm -rf WE/usr/share/doc 2>/dev/null
    rm -rf WE/usr/share/doc-base 2>/dev/null
    rm -rf WE/usr/share/fonts 2>/dev/null
    rm -rf WE/usr/share/locale 2>/dev/null
    rm -rf *.*
starthome 2>/dev/null
dir2fs $archiveDir/deb/WE $destinationDir/$FILE  || { echo 'apt2fs failed' ; exit 1; }
rm -rf $archiveDir
echo "Done. Module created"
```

Works flawlessly although there are some issues with the filesystem that prevents some modules from being used.